# Error when saving a LibreOffice Writer document

Tags: libreoffice

After typing a document, I am failing to save the document. There is a pop up that says Error saving the document 'nameofdocument': General error. General input/output error. How do I resolve this.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You may be trying to save to a disk or other medium that is defective; or to a network share that is no longer available. Can you use the file manager to create a dummy file in the same location?

Comment: Please look at `/var/log/syslog` for more info.

Comment: as part of your research in to this issue, are you able to open a document already saved using Writer and then use `Save As` to save it again in the same location but with a different name (thereby preserving the original)? Report back using [edit] rather than adding to the comment trail.

Comment: So I ended up installing another Libre office package and it is now working. Thank you